# Apache log: How to know if requests are being rejected, are waiting, etc

Tags: apache

I'm having issues with response times for my site and am trying to understand the Apache logs. However, I don't seem to get very much information from the access and error logs.

- Can I know how many requests were rejected by Apache?
- Can I see how many requests are waiting?
- Can I see how long requests had to wait before being served?
- Will the "server reached MaxClients setting" error be logged each time it happens or only once per server start?
- If the Apache access log only shows completed requests, how can I know how much traffic my site is really getting?

I occasionally see the "server reached MaxClients setting" message, but haven't worried about it too much since it's fairly uncommon. However, now I just read somewhere that the message will only be logged once between server restarts. Is that true, and if, so how can I know how big a problem this really is?

What I'm seeing client side is that a lot of calls aren't completed. For example, Ajax calls will go into the error() function, but without any specific error status, and with no error message. Also, the site feels sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

The access log only contains data about processed requests. If more traffic arrives than httpd can digest it will not even bother to log those. Typically a client would timeout and thus know there was no response.

So I guess either

- the OS could know how many TCP connections are accepted but waiting
- a network tool could know that no packages for a connection were sent
- the client could tell you. It might be a loadbalancer on your premises.